# Call to a member function rewrite() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php on line 165

Tags: magento-1.7, controllers, fatal-error

My site is not loading, as I get this error message when type in the URL:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function rewrite() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php on line 165

Does any one familiar with what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the file to which magento points out, you can find the below line which comes inside `dispatch` method

File : `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php`

```
$this->_getRequestRewriteController()->rewrite();
```

The error says `rewrite()` is calling on a `non-object`. This means that, `$this->_getRequestRewriteController()` provides you a `non-object` (most probably it returns an empty value).

Why `$this->_getRequestRewriteController()` gives you a `non-object` ? In order to find the reason, let us have a look on this method definition.

```
protected function _getRequestRewriteController()
{
    $className = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/request_rewrite/model');

    return Mage::getSingleton('core/factory')->getModel($className, array(
        'routers' => $this->getRouters(),
    ));
}
```

The method just trying to create a model instance of `$className`. Here `$className` holds a value which is returned by `$className = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/request_rewrite/model');`. The default value which return by this call is `core/url_rewrite_request`. This means the method `_getRequestRewriteController()` is supposed to return an instance of model class `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite_Request` by defalt.

Based on this analysis, the error may be caused due to

1. You may have a wrong class name in the above specified node. `app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml` is used to define this node value. Since it is a core file, alternation happens here may be a rare chance. There is a possibility of rewriting this node by any external plugins. So this should be validated first.
2. Ultimately your magento application do not have the file which defines this class `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite_Request` which normally appers at `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite/Request.php`
3. I have found out [**some threads**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11846/missing-request-rewrite-node-in-configuration), which gives a hint that permission problems on `var/cache` directory may also cause this weird issue.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue and I found that going into `var/cache` and deleting everything in there worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd share this with everyone: I got stuck in a situation like this. There was a problem with one of my mysql upgrade scripts and even though I had var folder and used apc.php to try and flush that cache out I was still hitting this problem. I finally got out of it by placing an `apc_clear_cache ('user');` command at the beginning of my index.php file which then allowed me to work through the upgrade script problems of which I had three. I then put my index.php back to what it was.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-clear-cache.php

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but i'm using redis, "flushall" from redis-cli did the trick

Answer (score 1):

This issue generally occurs when we upgrade Magento version. By the way for any reason if you have this issue, then first of all you should do this:

Clear cache

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
```